# How to increase the maximum execution timeout of aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing an application where I use MongoDB with Mongoose. There are some query which takes long time to give result.I know that `$maxTimeMS` can set maximum time for any find query but I want to set or increase query execution time for any aggregate method.How can I do that?

Comment: It's probably more of a concern that you have an aggregation statement that actually "times out". Perhaps you should show what you are trying to do and explain the output you are expecting. You really should not want to "increase" such a thing at all.

Comment: Which language and library are you using? Please mention it in the question.

Comment: @NeilLunn it's very feasible for an aggregation operation to time out. The default time is something like 30 seconds if I remember correctly and it can very quickly exceed the limit on large sets of data, specially when it involves operations such as sorting.

Comment: @AakashJain I am using mongoose for query.

Comment: @RonitSarma You would do well to follow the initial advise and actually show the operation you are running. There are outstanding issues with modifying "command cursors", so it's really not the best solution. In all likelyhood your "long running aggregation" can be improved. That should always be your first course of action anyway.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB's own node driver allows you to make the `aggregate` method use a cursor (it does not do this by default). When using a cursor, you can also provide it a `maxTimeMS` option to increase/decrease the timeout on the aggregate operation. [Documented here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#aggregate)

To do the same in Mongoose, you need to access the raw collection object for your model:

```
YourModel.collection.aggregate([/* pipeline */], {
  cursor: {
    batchSize: /* an appropriate batch size */
  },
  maxTimeMS: 60000
});
```

However, operations that run this long on MongoDB are not a good idea, so you should look into optimizing your pipeline or breaking it down. You may also want to make sure your collection is properly indexed.